# SQL AZURE IDENTITY (1,1)

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, identity-column

I am using SQL AZURE and I have a problem.
I have an id_pk at my table that is  identity(1,1). I started to save data at this table but suddenly, I noticed that my pk was not 1,2,3... anymore, it jumped from 38 to 1038, for example. 
After that kept inserting data  and it was normal, but suddenly, again, it did another jump, from 1043 to 2039.

Why is it happening? and how to fix it?

It happened not only at one table, but in 3 of them (at least I have noticed at 3 tables).

Comment: Any chance a user of yours inserted and deleted 1000 rows on you?

Comment: No, there aren't that chance. We are just testing until now, and just me and 2 of other friend can add and remove users.

Comment: Not sure then.  But I have to ask, does it matter enough to need fixing?  Identity columns are for the database to link records on and it matters little if the number is 1 or 102928301.

Comment: Well, I use INT to represent that id_pk. So, if the identities keep jumping like that, maybe it can achieve the max int too fast. but anyway, I can change it to long if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - I don't beleive anything is wrong here.  We can guess at a few explainations (insert and delete is my thought, but dunno), but it won't change anything.  Yes, the ID field is incrementing itself pretty rapidly, but the ID field is a behind the scene number that the database cares about and not much else.  In that light, I suggest no harm no foul, keep going.

If you do want to address this and 'reset' the ID field...create an identical table with the ID field set to 1,1 again.  Insert all the rows from the old table and put them in the new table...the ID's should then be sequential again.  Be warned that any other tables that have a foriegn key over to that ID field will likely lose it's relation.  I'd only attempt this as a last (very last) resort.